# 'version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found' on compiled application

Tags: command-line, c++

After building my application using `vamp-plugins`:

```
kokos@kokos-Latitude-E6230:~/repo/pitchtracker/pitchtracker$ ./vamp-simple-host -l
```

Following error occur:

```
./vamp-simple-host: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./vamp-simple-host)
./vamp-simple-host: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./vamp-simple-host)
```

I tried following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

`sudo apt-get update` and also `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${prefix}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And this:

```
mv -vf libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ./libstdc++.so.6
```

Caused a SERIOUS system error

Output of apt-cache policy libstdc++6:

```
libstdc++6:
  Zainstalowana: 7.1.0-5ubuntu2~14.04
  Kandydująca:   7.1.0-5ubuntu2~14.04
  Tabela wersji:
 *** 7.1.0-5ubuntu2~14.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 0
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

I've obtained vamp-plugins by compiling from source which I've downloaded from their official website:

```
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libstdc++6`. BTW how did you obtain and install the vamp plugin(s)?

Comment: @steeldriver I've added answer in the edit to my initial post. It worked on the other PC.

Comment: Hmm.. if you have successfully upgraded to libstdc++6 version `7.1.0-5ubuntu2~14.04`, you should have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.23` which should provide GLIBCXX versions up to 3.4.23 (you can confirm with `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.23 | grep 'GLIBCXX_'`). Do you still have a modified `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?